# WSO2 Enterprise Store 1.0.0: access control

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-es

Assets on WSO2 ES are retrieved by a **direct URL**, without access control.

Despite not assign permissions to **anonymous users**, once a user have the **URL to an asset**, everyone knowing that URL can download the resource.

Is there any plan to implement access control to assets?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug as the access rights are supposed to be checked before serving the resource.
The list of allowed roles are specified in the configuration files found in the ext/config/ folder .An example of its usage can be found in /store/config/ext/gadget.json;

```
"storage": {

    "images_banner": {

        "lifecycle": {
            "created": ["private_{overview_provider}"],
            "in-review": ["reviewer", "private_{overview_provider}"],
            "published": ["Internal/everyone", "private_{overview_provider}", "reviewer","anon"],
            "unpublished": ["private_{overview_provider}"]
        }
    },

    "images_thumbnail": {

        "lifecycle": {
            "created": ["private_{overview_provider}"],
            "in-review": ["reviewer", "private_{overview_provider}"],
            "published": ["Internal/everyone", "private_{overview_provider}", "reviewer","anon"],
            "unpublished": ["private_{overview_provider}"]
        }
    }

}
```

I have logged a JIRA for this issue [1] and we will have it fixed in the next release.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STORE-383

Thanks,
Sameera